# Need to create dynamic table in confluence

Tags: confluence

Can some please help how can i create the below table in confluence using JQL

I basically want to capture the value of custom fields present in issues along with its value .

table format required is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKUu1.png)

Format required

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGG9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll need to provide more details explaining what you've tried so far as a starting point and what isn't working as yet. However, before that - you'll have to provide the required table format which is missing from your question.

Comment: @costaparas : I tried using the JIRA Filter macro and created JQL to get the list of tickets and added the custom field and created table

Comment: @costaparas : I have attached the table which i created and also the format which is required

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a Jira macro.
2. Insert a JQL and press **Enter** to display a result table.
3. Click on **Display options** below the table.
4. In field **Columns to display**, select the columns you want to see in the result table.
5. Click **Insert** to finally insert the table into your page.